# Calling async method from ASP.NET page makes me wait for the result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, asynchronous

From my ASP.NET Page I call a method from a referenced project like this:

```
Dim oValServiceAgent As New ServiceAgents.ValServiceAgent(System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation, "ValEndPointName")
Using (CType(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity).Impersonate())
    oValServiceAgent.DoStuffAsync()
End Using
```

Referenced project ServiceAgents with class valServiceAgent:

```
public void DoStuffAsync()
{
    //invokes async method using delegates
}
```

I want the user to be able to navigate to a different page before the DoStuffAsync() is finished. In the current situation this is not possible.

I'm using VS2010 and target .NET framework 3.5

Comment: why is this not possible in the current situation?

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly happens?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click a link in the menu, not until the async method is finished...

Comment: It sounds like your code is waiting for a result when you don't want it to.

Comment: Sounds like the "async" method is not async at all... Can you be a little more explicit with the code inside it?

Comment: I'll dive deeper into this method at a later time (this is written by someone else). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the async method as Falanwe suggested, not in my asp.net code.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling Request.End() after you start the async process? That will force the current request to end right away. Not sure if that would work but something for you to try.

Note that launching background threads is not a preferable thing to do in web pages since you are not guaranteed that that thread will not be killed before completing what it is trying to complete because of app pool recycling. That thread becomes part of the current application pool and will be at the mercy of it after you kick it off. The approach I prefer is to queue the operation and process it outside of the web application instead. You can use whatever queue framework you would like or even roll your own by writing a record into a table or something.

Answer (score -1):

Here some points

- `async` and `await` keyword methods are .Net 4.5 features.
- async suffix is a convention only for methods that support async

More on async [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) in .Net 4.5

In .net 3.5 you should use [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) or a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to create your own asynchronous method.

We need more precision on your async method body to give you further help

Comment: Um...no.  Asynchronous methods have been in C#, in some form or another, since 2.0.  While the .NET framework has begun using the Async suffix much more frequently in the latest version, you can find [methods using that suffix as far back as 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploaddataasync(v=vs.80).aspx) that have nothing to do with tasks.

Comment: You are totally right.  I'll precise m'y poste as soon as possible.